# Is there any importance to notations like $| \Omega V\rangle$, $|aV\rangle$?

Tags: hilbert-space, notation, linear-algebra, quantum-states

I'm not really liking this notation. Before this notation, neither of bras and kets have any preference over the other. Either of $|V\rangle$ and $\langle V|$ can be understood as the adjoint of the other.

After that notation, kets have to be given a preference.

$|aV\rangle$ is interpreted the obvious way as $a|V\rangle$. But, we gotta interpret $ \langle aV|$ not as $a\langle V|$, but as the bra equivalent of $|aV\rangle$, which is $a^* \langle V|$

Same goes for $|\Omega V\rangle$ and $\langle \Omega V|$. The $\Omega$ operator becomes its adjoint in the bra case.

This forces us to think of bras in terms of the corresponding ket. Bras get to live in the shadow of kets.

Then why have we kept this confusing notation? Is there any importance to this?

Comment: This is a fairly subjective question. PSE isn't the place to discuss the merits/failures of notation. Is there a physics concept you are confused about that you could ask about instead?

Comment: @BioPhysicist No. I just wanted to know why we've stuck with this confusing notation. Is there any stackexchange site for this?

Comment: I am not sure, but if anyone is around there could be a discussion in the [hbar](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar)

Comment: If you think of ket + bra as half of a scalar product <x|y> = (x,y), then this is the only natural notation - you are taking a scalar product of two objects, and either object can be V, aV, or $\Omega V$. You might well argue that what is un-natural is to write things *between* ket and bra, since then no-one knows (without fixing a convention) on which side of the scalar product this should go. -- Of course, you still have to fix which of the components of your scalar product is sesquilinear.

Comment: @NorbertSchunch Couldn't we stick to writing the objects as $a\langle V|$ instead of as $\langle a V|$. The former is easily interpreted as the components of bra-V multiplied by $a$, while the latter MUST be interpreted as $a^* \langle V|$. This interpretation would give a preference to kets. Also, since matrix multiplication is associative, it doesn't matter which side $\Omega$ goes, right? And if that's important, we could use a symbol for inner product

Answer (score 0):

It will be better if you think that $|\rangle \in \mathcal{V}$ and $\langle |\in \mathcal{V}^*$ where $\mathcal{V}^*$ is dual space of $\mathcal{V}$. Similarly any scalar $\alpha \in \mathcal{F}$ and $\alpha\in \mathcal{F}^*$. Also Operators $\Omega$ act on $|\rangle \in  \mathcal{V}$ and for all $\Omega $ there exist $\Omega^\dagger$ that act  $\langle |\in \mathcal{V}^*$.

Now In $\mathcal{V}$,
$$\Omega |V\rangle =|\Omega V\rangle $$
$$\alpha|V\rangle=|\alpha V\rangle $$
and In dual,
$$\langle V|\alpha^*=\langle \alpha V|$$
$$\langle \Omega V|=\langle V|\Omega^\dagger$$

---

Further, When one writes $\Omega |V\rangle$, We mean that an operator acting on the vector while when we write $|\Omega V\rangle$, It's a transformed vector. It can't be said using this has many merits. But consider an example

Let's prove that the energy of the Harmonics oscillator can't be less than zero.

$$\langle \psi|H|\psi\rangle =\langle \psi|P^2|\psi\rangle +\langle \psi|X^2|\psi\rangle =\langle P\psi|P\psi\rangle +\langle X\psi|X\psi\rangle\geq 0$$
Using the fact, that norm of a vector is greater or equal to zero. It was useful to write that way to see the norm of vector.

Comment: But I don't see why we couldn't interpret $P\langle V|$ both as $P$ applied to $V$, and as the vector we get after applying $P$ to $V$. As an analogy, $2x$ is both a number on its own and also $x$ multiplied by 2

Comment: The notation $\langle P V|$ forces us to think of this bra as arising from the corresponding ket. This results in a preference to kets which really shouldn't be there.

Comment: @RyderRude No $P\in \mathcal{V}$ and so act only on kets.

Comment: @RyderRude I don't understand what's you mean in your second comment.